# JSF/Java Beans/Richfaces testing solution (JSFUnit, JUnit, etc)

Tags: unit-testing, jsf, richfaces, jsfunit

I'm currently looking into approaches for creating automated unit tests for any new code created in our web based application. We are running JSF 2.0, Richfaces 3.3 and using JRE1.6.

I'd be interested in hearing opinions on what people have used and would recommend?
Advantages/Disadvantages? Difficulty to implement? Community support and documentation? Etc.

I have had a look at JSFUnit and it seems quite compressive, but would like to get opinions before I go ahead and start using it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSFUnit is indeed the typical approach. I, however, have used [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) for functional testing, and it worked fine.

The thing is, in many cases the front-end is more easily tested in terms of functional scenarios, rather than units.

Comment: Thanks Bozho, and everyone else for their suggestions. I'm going to have a look at Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [SeleniumHQ](http://seleniumhq.org/). Tests are executed in a real Browser which is operated by the test engine. It's funny and little spooky to watch the browser while a test is running.

There is also add-on on top of Selenium which makes it more comftable to write test, called: [Selenium Inspector](http://seleniuminspector.org/).

Answer (score 0):

For automated web testing, we are using [Windmill](http://www.getwindmill.com/).

Its great. You record what you want to test in your browser, and windmill will fire up firefox, and run the tests.
Its written in python and works for all web pages.

We have integrated Windmill in our continuous integration environment (hudson) so that the tests always run for each commit.

[Here is a introduction video to Windmill](http://www.getwindmill.com/features/windmill-introduction-video)

[And here is a windmill talk on parleys.com](http://parleys.com/#id=1598&sl=1&st=5)

Comment: Haven't heard about this before. Do you also have Selenium experience? If so, how is Windmill better/different?

Comment: No I have no Selenium experience, but I have head or it. We are using it heavily, and it very easy to use. It supports JQuery, so you can easily program events and modify the tests for your page. There is also a Windmill talk from parleys.com. Check it out